# set width and height properties of class for the loaded images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image array **images**  having four random images,

background-image in style of css of class **contents**  change son each button click ,have  **buildimage** and **changeImage**

Is it possible to **set width and height** of each **image** loaded into the class **contents** to be the s**ame width and height of the class**

How to achieve it?

```js
var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {

    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+images[index]+')';

}

function changeImage() {
    index++;
    if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
}
```

```css
.contents {
    width: 70%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
p{
color:#00FF00;}
```

```html
<div class="contents" id="content"><p>set background image height ans width same as this box </p></div>
<button onclick="changeImage()">NextImage</button>
```

Comment: You can simply achieve it using `background-size: 100% 100%;` - is that what you want?

Comment: try  background-size:cover;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use CSS to scale the image, setting the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to 100%:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

That way, the image is scaled exactly like the dimension of its container. Here is the working example:

```js
var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {

  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';

}

function changeImage() {
  index++;
  if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
}
```

```css
.contents {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #FF0000;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

p {
  color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents" id="content">
  <p>set background image height ans width same as this box </p>
</div>
<button onclick="changeImage()">NextImage</button>
```

Comment: oh we have to correct it in css , now i understand.. Thanks for reply

Comment: You're welcome! If this post was helpful for you, I appreciate an accept/upvote :) Have a nice day!

Comment: im verymuch in that